# string is nil when unmarshaling json in Golang

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a json in Golang, which looks like this:

```
{"graph":[[1650970800,1859857],[1650972600,1918183]...],"records":246544,"period":"24h","zone":"test.com","queries":93321}
```

While I can unmarshal some of the values, others are simply empty i.e `zone` or `graph` (but those values are returned in the Json). Here's my code

```
type NSoneResponse struct {
Graphs  []Graph
Records int64
Period  string
Zones   string
Queries int64
}

type Graph struct {
    Timestamp int64
    Queries   int64
}

const (
    zoneUsageUrl  = "https://api.nsone.net/v1/stats/usage/test.com?period=24h&networks=*"
)

func main() {
    getUsageData(zoneUsageUrl)
}

func getUsageData(url string) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var filteredData []NSoneResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &filteredData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := range filteredData {
        fmt.Printf("Quieries per timestamp: %v\nRecords count: %v\nPeriod: %v\nZone: %v\nNumber of queries: %v\n", filteredData[i].Graphs, filteredData[i].Records, filteredData[i].Period, filteredData[i].Zones, filteredData[i].Queries)

    }
}
```

The output at the end

```
Quieries per timestamp: []
Record count: 243066
Period: 24h
Zone:
Number of queries: 91612963
```

When I tried to use pointers in the NSoneResponse struct, I got nil for those values instead (note - the `Period` key also contains string value, yet it does not return nil)

```
Quieries per timestamp: <nil>
Quota count: 0xc000274470
Period: 0xc000460310
Zone: <nil>
Number of queries: 0xc000274488
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `NSoneResponse` struct's field you've declared as `Zones`. Does the json contains a `"zones"` property? Or does it perhaps contain a `"zone"` property? You are aware that `zones` != `zone`, are you not? Same for `graphs` and `graph`.

Comment: Note that there are no nil strings in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I will explain the mistake in your code, you should use [`struct tags`](https://zetcode.com/golang/struct-tag/). because your `Graphs` variable of your struct is not equal of `graph` in your json, this mistake is on `zone` variable too.  change your struct to this :

```
type NSoneResponse struct {
    Graphs  [][]int `json:"graph"`
    Records int64   `json:"records"`
    Period  string  `json:"period"`
    Zones   string  `json:"zone"`
    Queries int64   `json:"queries"`
}
```

also, your JSON has an array of int not an array of Objects, so you must change the type of `Graphs`. after that, you should convert the array of int to an array of graphs.